# Fullpage JS onLeave fixed image

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

Here is what I am looking for,

```
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section" id="section1"><h1>Content 1</h1></div>
<div class="section" id="section2"><h1>Content 2</h1><img src="imgs/man.png"/></div>
<div class="section" id="section3"><h1>Content 3</h1></div>
<div class="section" id="section4"><h1>Content 4</h1></div>
<div class="section" id="section5"><h1>Content 5</h1></div>
<div class="section" id="section6"><h1>Content 6</h1></div>
```

There is an image in second section, usually it will appear when the user scroll to second section, it will go away when user scroll to next section,instead of that i want that image should stay in the third section also, like that from 2nd section to 6th section the image should stay. 2nd to 6th contents should scroll, basically that image should act like background image from second section in fixed position. There is an example in the fullpage.js(Apple).

Can anyone help to work on this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1x7J.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you just take a look at the Apple example of fullPage.js and see how it is doing it?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is [StcikImage](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_sticky.asp).
Use `position:` attribute in css for the Image Tag or wrapper for that image.

```
img.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

[StcikImage](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_sticky.asp)

Comment: i have attached an reference image, please have a look at that